# Show that these two sum forms are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am trying to prove the following **lemma** (related to formal derivatives for reference):

Let $R$ be a ring, $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+ (\text{this means }k\geq 1)$, and $f_0,\dots,f_k,g_0,\dots,g_k\in R$. Then
$$k\sum_{l=0}^{k}f_lg_{k-l} = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\Big[(k-l)f_lg_{k-l}+(l+1)f_{l+1}g_{k-l-1}\Big].$$

I am currently trying induction and this result certainly holds for k=1 and k=2.

I am currently lost in the inductive step and suspect there may be some substitution trick I am unaware of.

(***Current Attempt***)

In short, I've tried the following: If we assume the result holds for $k=n\geq 1$, then $k=n+1\Rightarrow$
$$RHS = \sum_{l=0}^{n}\Big[(n+1-l)f_lg_{n+1-l}+(l+1)f_{l+1}g_{n-l}\Big] \text{ and}$$
$$LHS = (n+1)\sum_{l=0}^{n+1}f_lg_{n+1-l}.$$

If you algebraically manipulate the RHS, you can see that most of the LHS cancels with it. Not sure if this is the best approach if I plan to use the inductive hypothesis. With this route and working backwards, I currently have that
$$LHS=RHS \leftrightarrow (n+1)f_{n+1}g_0 = \sum_{l=0}^n\Big[(l+1)f_{l+1}g_{n-l} - lf_lg_{n+1-l}\Big].$$

Currently looking for advice or key insights, potentially a better strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with the right-hand side. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}}&\color{blue}{\Big[(k-l)f_lg_{k-l}+(l+1)f_{l+1}g_{k-l-1}\Big]}\\
&=k\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}f_lg_{k-l}-\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}lf_lg_{k-l}+\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}(l+1)f_{l+1}g_{k+1-l}\\
&=k\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}f_lg_{k-l}-\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}lf_lg_{k-l}+\sum_{l=1}^{k}lf_lg_{k-l}\tag{1}\\
&=k\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}f_lg_{k-l}+kf_kg_0\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=k\sum_{l=0}^{k}f_lg_{k-l}}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index of the right-most sum to start with $l=1$.
- In (2) we cancel terms thanks to telescoping.

Comment: A smooth direct strategy. Thank you for your post.

Comment: @northcity4: You're welcome.